# looping Blog pages in Newsletter Silverstripe add-on

Tags: php, silverstripe, newsletter

I want to loop my Blog Post in my Silverstripe newsletter themes
I use this snippet in my Page controller:

```
function GetPageByType($class) { 
$pages = $class::get();
return $pages->count() ? $pages->first() : false; 
}
```

and these in my template:

```
<% with GetPageByType(Blog) %>
<% loop $PaginatedList %>
      <div class="is-collapsed">
        $FeaturedImage
        $Title
      </div>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_with %>
```

I loop from my menumanager module and it's work but i can't looping my Pages
How can i loop from my Blog & the other pages?

Comment: Can you post the context around the template snippet? (E.g. what the scope is).

Comment: I want to loop my 3 last blog post
and my 4 last Product (Product is child of Product holder)

Comment: What I am asking is more information on your code examples. (E.g. Template name, how the template is included, which controller the function is defined in, etc). SilverStripe templates work from "Scope" so you may be trying to access functionality of a scope outside of your current standing.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the GetPageByType() method will return either the first blog post, or false (if there are no blog posts).

I would change it to something like this:

```
function GetPageByType($class) { 
    $pages = $class::get();
    return $pages;
}
```

The code above it's perfectly ok... if there are no blog posts it will return null, otherwise it will return all the blog posts, not just the first one.